# In Postgres how can I combine two group by queries and do simple division with the results?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

If I can do this query from table bars:

```
SELECT count(distinct bar_id) as count, 
       date_trunc('day', created_at) as date
FROM 
  bars
GROUP BY 
  date 
ORDER BY 
  date desc
```

And this query from table foos:

```
SELECT count(distinct foo_id),
       date_trunc('day', created_at) as date
FROM 
  foos
GROUP BY 
  date 
ORDER BY 
  date desc
```

I get back nice lists like:

```
22, 2017-09-14
31, 2017-09-13
18, 2017-09-12
```

and this:

```
34, 2017-09-14
55, 2017-09-13
67, 2017-09-12
```

In one query, how do I combine these two to produce:

```
22/34, 0.64, 2017-09-14
31/55, 0.56, 2017-09-13
18/67, 0.26, 2017-09-12
```

i.e. I want to divide each count from table1 grouped by the day from table2 grouped by the day.  22 / 34 = 0.64, 31 / 55 = 0.56 etc.

Comment: Simply `join` the two by date then run the division.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join them:

```
SELECT bars.counts * 1.0 / foos.counts
    , bars.date
FROM
(
SELECT count(distinct bar_id) as counts, 
       date_trunc('day', created_at) as date
FROM 
  bars
GROUP BY 
  date 
) bars_q
JOIN
(
SELECT count(distinct foo_id) as counts,
       date_trunc('day', created_at) as date
FROM 
  foos
GROUP BY 
  date 
) foos_q
ON bars_q.date = foos_q.date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FULL OUTER JOIN to retrieve records on both tables and would also show records with no matching dates

```
SELECT CONCAT(COUNT(DISTINCT bar_id),'/',COUNT(distinct foo_id)) cnt,
       CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT bar_id) AS FLOAT)/CASE WHEN COUNT(distinct foo_id) = 0
                                                  THEN 1
                                                  ELSE CAST(COUNT(distinct foo_id) AS FLOAT)
                                              END "div",
       CASE WHEN DATE_TRUNC('day', b.created_at) IS NULL
            THEN DATE_TRUNC('day', f.created_at)
            ELSE DATE_TRUNC('day', b.created_at)
        END "date"       
  FROM bars b
  FULL OUTER JOIN foos f
    ON date_trunc('day', b.created_at) = date_trunc('day', f.created_at)
 GROUP BY "date"
 ORDER BY "date" DESC
```